# How to create an image with rounded corners in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

When I draw the BufferedImage with rounded corners

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
graphics.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 60, 60, 20, 20));
```

The output image is:

[image]

How can I receive an image without black cornerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to create a transparent image